# Calling two different endpoints in the same screen with Retrofit

Tags: android, mvvm, retrofit

I am having two endpoints that has a lists and trying to display them in Recycleview. But its works only with one, when I try to implement second one it's not showing. When I comment out first one than the second one is showing. When I try to debug it tells me that one model can not be casted in another, but I'm not trying to cast anything

my ViewModel: `

```
 public class ExpensesViewModel extends ViewModel {
        private ExpensesFragmentCallBack callBack;
        private ApiCallsRepository apiCallsRepository;
        private MutableLiveData<ApiResponseObject> responseLiveData = new MutableLiveData<>();
        private CompositeDisposable disposables = new CompositeDisposable();
        private Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getDefault());
        int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
    
        public ExpensesViewModel(ExpensesFragmentCallBack callBack) {
            this.callBack = callBack;
            apiCallsRepository = new ApiCallsRepository();
        }
        public void getFixedExpenses() {
            disposables.add(apiCallsRepository.getFixedExpenses(year, month)
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .doOnSubscribe(d -> responseLiveData.setValue(ApiResponseObject.loading()))
                    .subscribe(
                            result -> {
                                responseLiveData.setValue(ApiResponseObject.success(result));
                            }, this::handleError));
    
        }
    
    
        public void getFluctuatedExpenses() {
            disposables.add(apiCallsRepository.getFluctuatedExpenses(year, month)
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .doOnSubscribe(d -> responseLiveData.setValue(ApiResponseObject.loading()))
                    .subscribe(
                            result -> {
                                responseLiveData.setValue(ApiResponseObject.success(result));
                            }, this::handleError));
        }
    
        private void handleError(Throwable throwable) {
            if (throwable instanceof HttpException) {
                HttpException httpException = (HttpException) throwable;
                Response<?> response = httpException.response();
                responseLiveData.setValue(ApiResponseObject.error(response.message()));
            } else if (throwable instanceof IOException) {
                responseLiveData.setValue(ApiResponseObject.error(UNEXPECTED_ERROR));
            } else {
                responseLiveData.setValue(ApiResponseObject.error(throwable.getMessage()));
            }
        }
        MutableLiveData<ApiResponseObject> myFixedExpensesResponse() {
            return responseLiveData;
        }`
```

and my fragment:

1.

```
`public class ExpensesFragment extends Fragment implements
    ExpensesFragmentCallBack {
    
        private ExpensesViewModel viewModel;
        private FragmentExpensesBinding binding;
        private Activity context;
        private NavController navController;
        private ApiService apiService;
        private MyPlanExpenses expensesModel;
        private DailySpending dailySpendingModel;
    
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                                 @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_expenses, container, false);
            context = getActivity();
            if (context == null) throw new AssertionError();
            viewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this, new ExpensesFragmentViewModelFactory(this)).get(ExpensesViewModel.class);
            navController = NavHostFragment.findNavController(this);
            binding.setExpense(viewModel);
            apiService = ApiUtils.getApiService();
            viewModel.myFixedExpensesResponse().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(),this::consumeResponse);
                viewModel.getFixedExpenses();
                viewModel.getFluctuatedExpenses();
                return binding.getRoot();
    
        }
    
    
        private void consumeResponse(ApiResponseObject apiResponse) {
            switch (apiResponse.status) {
                case LOADING:
                    showProgressDialog(context);
                    break;
                case SUCCESS:
                    hideProgressDialog();
                    hideKeyboard(context);
                    expensesModel = (MyPlanExpenses) apiResponse.object;
                  //  dailySpendingModel = (DailySpending) apiResponse.object;
                    setUpFixedMoyhlyExpensesRecycleView(expensesModel.getFixedMonthlyEspensesList());
                    setUpReletedMonthlyExpensesRecycleView(expensesModel.getReletedMonthlyExpenses());
                   //setUpDailyExpensesRecycleView(dailySpendingModel.getExpensesDailySpendingList());
                   setUpTaxesRecycleView(expensesModel.getTaxesList());
                    Log.i(TAG,"Uspesno ucitano");
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Sucess", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    setUpDailyExpenseView(apiResponse);
                    break;
                case ERROR:
                    hideProgressDialog();
                    Toast.makeText(context,getStringResourceByName(context,apiResponse.error),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    
        private void setUpDailyExpenseView(ApiResponseObject apiResponseObject){
            dailySpendingModel = (DailySpending) apiResponseObject.object;
            setUpDailyExpensesRecycleView(dailySpendingModel.getExpensesDailySpendingList());
        }
    
        private void setUpDailyExpensesRecycleView(List<ExpensesDailySpending> list) {
    
            RecyclerView recyclerView = binding.rvDailyList;
            DailySpendingCategoryAdapter adapter = new DailySpendingCategoryAdapter (list, context );
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            // recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));
        }
    
        private void setUpReletedMonthlyExpensesRecycleView(List<ReletedMonthlyExpenses>
    list) {
    
            RecyclerView recyclerView = binding.rvRelatedExpenseList;
            ReletedMonthlyExpensesAdapter adapter = new ReletedMonthlyExpensesAdapter (list, context );
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            // recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));
        }
    
        private void setUpTaxesRecycleView(List<Taxes> list) {
    
            RecyclerView recyclerView = binding.rvTaxesList;
            TaxAdapter adapter = new TaxAdapter (list, context );
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            // recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));
        }
    
    
        private void setUpFixedMoyhlyExpensesRecycleView(List<FixedMonthlyEspenses> list)
    {
    
            RecyclerView recyclerView = binding.rvFixedExpensesList;
            FixedMonthlyExpenesAdapter adapter = new FixedMonthlyExpenesAdapter (list, context );
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            // recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));
        }`
```

Comment: Why are you calling both Api sequentially? if thats  the need have the separate response `LiveData`  for each . Also do not pass `callBack` from fragment to `ViewModel` this is violating the purpose of `MVVM` i.e loose coupling.

Comment: You can use Observable.zip() to execute two calls in parallel

Comment: @ADM I must, it's two different model created from different endpoints. You think to create another MutableLive data in my ViewModel class? And then in my fragment to create another consumeResponse method and there to populate RecycleView?